# Dynamic memory and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memory, header, malloc

I'm making a program that has to allocate memory for a certain type and it has to store the size of the data and also the size of the data I passed to it. So if I allocate 8 bytes I need to store the size of memory in the first 4 bytes and store the remaining size in the other 4 bytes. I think this is referred to has headers, but I'm still fairly new to C.
All I have right now is the allocated space, how do I store values in that?

```
int * mem_start_ptr; //pointer to start off memory block
    int data; 
    data = &mem_start_ptr; 
    mem_start_ptr = (long *)malloc(sizeof(long)); //reserver 8 bytes
```

Comment: wait.. I do not understand the question

Comment: long type does not have 8 bytes, it has 4. If you want 8 bytes you need long long.

Comment: @FredericoSchardong: It depends on your platform.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth which platform the long type has 8 bytes?

Comment: @FredericoSchardong: e.g. GCC on x86.

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to explain. Basically when I start the program it should allocate some space, I'm using 8 bytes. After that I have a function that you can pass in either an int, float, or char. However after it allocates all I know is the pointer to memory, so I have to store how much space I have, and how much I used (in a header?), so that when I allocate again, I'll know how much space to allocate. 
Does that help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `sizof(long)` is implementation specific and is 8 bytes on 64bit Linux, yet 4 bytes on Windows and 32bit Linux, AFAIK. Use `malloc(8)` if You want to allocate 8 bytes explicitly. Although, since You want to store `int`, it seems, use `malloc(sizeof(*mem_start_ptr))`. Also, don't cast the return value of `malloc`, it is redundant in C and can even hide bugs.
Now, to store those two 4 byte values:

```
/* for the first one. Let's use 42 */
*mem_start_ptr = 42;
/* for the second one. Let's put the value of of some variable here */
*(mem_start_ptr + 1) = int_variable;
```

You should read about pointer arithmetic. And also probably about arrays. Google is Your friend. Also, no idea what this part in Your code is for. **As it does not do what You probably expect it to do**:

```
int data;
data = &mem_start_ptr
```

In the end, I'd rewrite Your code like this:

```
int *mem_start_ptr;
mem_start_ptr = malloc(sizeof(*mem_start_ptr));
*mem_start_ptr = your_1st_4bytes;
*(mem_start_ptr + 1) = your_2nd_4bytes;
```

Don't forget to `free()` it after it is no longer needed. Also, I did not shot it here, but also don't forget to check for `NULL`, as `malloc()` returns that on failure.

Yet again - read about pointer arithmetics. Google is Your friend ;]

Comment: ok, so I can simply assign a value to the *mem_start_ptr and it will automatically store that value in the first part of memory. Then I can iterate thru that to find out the second part?

Comment: @Nelson.b.austin yes, sort of. It works in almost the same way an array works. Actually, you can even do `mem_start_ptr[0]` for the first one and `mem_start_ptr[1]` for the second one. And it will still be perfectly valid && correct. Though, You should REALLY read about pointer arithmetics and dynamic memory allocation. Google is Your friend there =]